# New line in html text

Tags: html, text, line

I am trying to place some text on my html website and it has a space in it.

```
<div class="text">

text text   

</div>
```

When I open the website, it doesn`t display it as a space, but it goes to a new line between the 2 words. How do I type out a space?

Comment: Make you `<div>` wide enough then your text will not wrap. Maybe we can offer better help if you show us the style of `class="text"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the space in the `div` you can use `white-space: pre`:

```css
.text{ white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<div class="text">

text text   

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `<br>` element.

```html
top stuff
<div class="text">
  <br>
  text text   
  <br>
  <br>
  more text
<div>
```

You can read more about `<br>` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5qs30nu/1/)

Note that you need two br's to seporate two lines of text, and one for the equivalent of a carriage return. None, puts the second line on top of the first.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OPs issue. He complains about his to words **being separated by line wrapping** instead of **being displayed in one line separated by a space**.